# jQuery UI get property of element in draggable div on drop:

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, draggable, jquery-callback

```
$('#drop_area').droppable({
    accept: '.draggable',
    drop: on_element_drop
});

function on_element_drop(event, ui){

}

<div class="draggable">
    <img src="test.png" alt="3">
</div>
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can get the 'alt' property of the image in this draggable div from the 'ui' argument passed to 'on_element_drop.' Anyone know how to do this?

The closest I seem to get is:

```
ui.helper.context.children[0].attr('alt');
```

however this doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ui.draggable.find("img").attr("alt")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3SfBJ/2

Answer (score 2):

Your draggable div contain only one img element. So for this below is right

```
 ui.draggable.find("img").attr("alt")
                  OR
 ui.draggable.children("img").attr("alt")
```

But if your draggable contain more img element like below

```
<div class="draggable">
    <img src="test.png" alt="3">
    <img src="test.png" alt="4">
</div>
```

then you can't use upper code to find alt value of second img element. So you can try this:

```
ui.draggable.find("img:last-child").attr("alt")
                   OR
ui.draggable.children("img:last-child").attr("alt")
```

This example shows a general idea that how you can find actual object within parent object.
You can use classes to differentiate your child object. That is easy and fun. i.e.

```
<div class="draggable">
    <img class='first' src="test.png" alt="3">
    <img class='second' src="test.png" alt="4">
</div>
```

You can do this as below :

```
ui.draggable.find(".first").attr("alt")
```

and more specific as:

```
ui.draggable.find("img.first").attr("alt")
```

You can use find or children as above code. For more visit Children http://api.jquery.com/children/ and Find http://api.jquery.com/find/.

Answer (score 1):

I assume there is more html and javascript to go with what you have posted? Like the droppable div?

You should be able to add this to your drop handler

```
ui.draggable.children(0).attr('alt')
```

Using find works as well, if you add extra html

```
ui.draggable.find('img').attr('alt');
```

Good luck!